# Can I upload video file more than 4GB in visual studio 2005 using c# web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, video

How can i upload video files of large size more than 4GB in web server using web service written in c# under visual studio 2005, without going for the silverlight concepts and framework 4.0. I need to make available this service within 2008, because my server is configured to 2008. I cant use silverlight which is present in visual studio 2012.

Any suggestions for implementing this concept is welcomed.

Comment: Visual studio 2008 is not the same as windows server 2008. Windows server can handle framework 4.0. Further, Silverlight is a client language, so that's really what your users can handle. For uploading large files check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935040/how-to-handle-large-file-uploads-via-wcf

Comment: ASMX web services are not efficient with large files. There will be times when the complete message resides in memory two or even four times. Upgrade to VS2010 or 2012 and use WCF, which allows for true streaming.

Comment: If I'm using visual studio 2008 (c# web service), what is the maximum file(video) size can be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7) for the current IIS size limit and [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1766127.aspx/1) for additional timeout settings and [this article](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/large_files_iis_asp_net) for some suggestions on how to do what you want with a custom client app, I don't think it would work directly from the browser. Here is a [summary](http://www.motobit.com/help/ScptUtl/pa33.htm) of the IIS limits and the most popular browsers.

---

Based on the above I think the safest thing you can do is impose a limit to the end user; something like 500 megs per file sounds reasonable.

---

On a similar note, apparently Apache has removed this kind of limitations in 2005 ...