# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large in WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am developing WCF service with the following operation contract;

```
    [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddHCPRankAttachment", RequestFormat =
WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        WSMessage AddHCPRankAttachment(HCPRankAttachmentEnt HCPAttachment, byte[] ImageInBytes);
```

When I call it like this:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client s = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
s.AddHCPRankAttachment(new HCPRankAttachmentEnt()
                {
                    AttachmentType = "a",
                    CreationDate = null,
                    HCPRankID = 1,
                    UserID = "EMP0000001",
                    Remarks = "rem"
                }, ary);
```

Where ary is my image converted to bytes ( Image size is 582 KB). I receive error

> The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large in
>   WCF Service.

I added the following to my web.config and restarted the website application in IIS, but still the same error.

```
<bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
```

Comment: its better you create image and send path of it and then read image from path ...

Comment: The caller of the web service is a remote user that I do not have access to his PC.

Comment: if you send path like `http://domain/image` ..then it will work

Comment: can you elaborate more please? and this means that the user should have some sort of a domain?

Comment: i am suggesting , you create images in your server directory ..lets say temp and once created you include path of the image in your response like `http://yourdomain/imagefolder/imagename.extenstion`..that should work that whats we do when we provide html page

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstand, the user should send me the picture not me sending him.

Comment: ok got you ...can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935040/how-to-handle-large-file-uploads-via-wcf

Comment: Thank you , solved it. By the way you gave me an idea on how to send pic to the user, I will use your proposed method (sending the link) thank you!